# Bash script qpdf to split multiple pdfs in 1 directory

Tags: linux, ubuntu, qpdf

I wrote a simple bash script as I need to split multiple pdfs into 2 pdfs on a regular basis. I need them to be split in the same sequence each time (pages 1-5 and 6 to last page). I need the newly split pdfs to be named uniquely so I can keep them apart (i.e. inv-1.pdf rec-1.pdf; inv-2.pdf rec-2.pdf, etc). My script only splits the 1 pdf when I have 5+ in the folder. Any suggestions are appreciated.

```
    #!/bin/bash
    for file in $(ls REQ*.pdf)

    do
        qpdf ${file} --pages . 1-5 -- inv-%d.pdf |\
        qpdf ${file} --pages . 6-z -- rec-%d.pdf |\
        echo >> ${file}
    done
```

'''

Comment: I recommend you check your script via [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) ...

Comment: And a useful debugging technique to see whether the looping happens:  before the first `qpdf` line, insert an `echo ${file}` ...

Answer (score 0):

Quick solution: Append `| xargs echo` to your `ls` command.

```sh
    #!/bin/bash
    for file in $(ls REQ*.pdf | xargs echo)

    do
        qpdf ${file} --pages . 1-5 -- inv-%d.pdf |\
        qpdf ${file} --pages . 6-z -- rec-%d.pdf |\
        echo >> ${file}
    done
```

Rationale: In your case, `ls` output is one filename per line. Your `for` loop picks up the filename in the same line only. The rest get ignored. You can read more about `ls` output behavior on this answer- [What is the magic separator between filenames in ls output?](https://superuser.com/questions/424246/what-is-the-magic-separator-between-filenames-in-ls-output)

The pipe (`|`) redirects `ls` output to `xargs` which applies `echo` to generate space-separated file names on a single line.
Read more about `xargs` on the [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html)

Comment: @tink tried your suggestion, thank you! It still only works to separate 1 file into 2 pdfs. The loop does not work on more than 1 REQ file in the folder.

Comment: tried your suggestion, thank you! It still only works to separate 1 file into 2 pdfs. The loop does not work on more than 1 REQ file in the folder.

Comment: Is it incidentally naming all the output files with the same name? That would be a case of overwriting. You can try incrementing an index variable inside the loop and use this variable in the output filenames.

Comment: no i think it is simply creating split pdfs for 1 file only. How do I increment an index variable inside the loop? I rewrote the code to try qpdf --empty --pages "${file}" 1-5 -- inv-%d.pdf but I still only get 1 file output for all pdfs in the folder.